# LINQ subquery with multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to recreate this SQL query in LINQ:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Policies 
WHERE  PolicyID IN(SELECT PolicyID 
                   FROM   PolicyRegister 
                   WHERE  PolicyRegister.StaffNumber = @CurrentUserStaffNo 
                          AND ( PolicyRegister.IsPolicyAccepted = 0 
                                 OR PolicyRegister.IsPolicyAccepted IS NULL ))
```

Relationship Diagram for the two tables:

[image: Relationship Diagram]

Here is my attempt so far:

```
var staffNumber = GetStaffNumber();

var policyRegisterIds = db.PolicyRegisters
                        .Where(pr => pr.StaffNumber == staffNumber && (pr.IsPolicyAccepted == false || pr.IsPolicyAccepted == null))
                        .Select(pr => pr.PolicyID)
                        .ToList();

var policies = db.Policies.Where(p => p.PolicyID.//Appears in PolicyRegisterIdsList)
```

I think I'm close, will probably make two lists and use Intersect() somehow but I looked at my code this morning and thought there has to be an easier way to do this,. LINQ is supposed to be a more readble database language right?

Any help provided is greatly appreciated.

Comment: db.Policies.Where(p => policyRegisterIds .Contains(p.PolicyID))

Comment: try `policyRegisterIds.Contains( p.PolicyID)`, but it's better to make a join to minimize amount of requests

Comment: Do you have a virtual relation between `Policies` and `PolicyRegisters` ? Include the structures in Question

Comment: @meorfi Yes, PolicyID forms part of a composite key in PolicyRegister

Comment: @TridentTrue C# structure of PolicyRegister would be great. I am just curios if in 1 single Query is possible to achieve your goal, That depends on your configurations :)

Comment: @meorfi I edited the relationship diagram into the OP, unless you're looking something else?

Comment: @TridentTrue, yes, I saw the diagram. I am interested how you've structured the C# Classes which corresponds to these 2 tables + their relations. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Contains`:

```
var policies = db.Policies.Where(p => policyRegisterIds.Contains(p.PolicyID));
```

*Also better store `policyRegisterIds` as a `HashSet<T>` instead of a list for search in `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` of `List<T>`:*

```
var policyRegisterIds = new HashSet<IdType>(db.PolicyRegisters......);
```

---

But better still is to remove the `ToList()` and let it all happen as one query in database:

```
var policyRegisterIds = db.PolicyRegisters.Where(pr => pr.StaffNumber == staffNumber && 
                            (pr.IsPolicyAccepted == false || pr.IsPolicyAccepted == null));

var policies = db.Policies.Where(p => policyRegisterIds.Any(pr => pr.PolicyID == p.PolicyID));
```

Comment: thumbs up for `HashSet<T>` suggestion

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - I like it too :) and if it was in memory linq I'd go for it for sure

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help :)